# How to reduce the memory used by a trained workflow

Tags: r, tidymodels

I have trained a workflow with the `tidymodels` framework. The fit uses random forest and its size is ~ 2.06 GB. After calling `butcher::butcher()` function on it, still occupies around 2 GB of memory. I get better results with `extract_fit_parsnip()`, which reduces the object size to ~ 1.86 GB.

Is there a way to reduce the memory used by the model any further? I only need a minimal object to make predictions, that includes the recipe instructions for preprocessing.

The reproduce the example, you will need to download the data from [this kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/tabular-playground-series-feb-2022/data).

```
library(tidymodels)
set.seed(112)
splits <- initial_split(bacteria)
bacteria_train <- training(splits)
bacteria_test <- testing(splits)

preprocessing <- recipe(target ~ ., data = bacteria_train) %>% 
  update_role(row_id, new_role = "id") %>% 
  step_zv(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_corr(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_pca(all_numeric_predictors())

rf_spec <- rand_forest(trees = 1000) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_engine("ranger")

rf_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(preprocessing) %>% 
  add_model(rf_spec)

# Training takes around 13 minutes
rf_fit <- fit(rf_wf, data = bacteria_train)

rf_fit %>% lobstr::obj_size()
rf_fit %>% butcher::butcher() %>% lobstr::obj_size()
rf_fit %>% extract_fit_parsnip() %>% butcher::butcher() %>% lobstr::obj_size()
```

Answer (score 0):

A random forest model can get very big, especially when you have a lot of predictors. This is just the nature of a random forest, because all the trees you trained must be stored, with all their nodes, etc.

- You can try reducing the number of trees. In fact, you can *tune* the number of trees, and find the smallest number that works well.
- If you are using a random forest, you likely do not need to normalize, create PC components, etc. Random forests are known for being low-maintenance when it comes to feature engineering. Try using only your raw predictors and see how much improvement that feature engineering really gets you.

You can also try out other types of models, which in my experience often have smaller memory footprints than random forest. Some ideas to try include a bagged tree model and an xgboost model.

Comment: I will try smaller models. What I found to be seldom is that a bagged tree model with the same preprocessor, mtry and trees numbers is much smaller, like 300 MB, but after butchering its size diminishes to 70 KB.
Also, the butchered random forest throws an error when combined with predict.